# typo3 extbase record storage for inline object in backend

Tags: listview, typo3, storage, backend, extbase

I create TYPO3 extabase records in the backend, list view. When I use the fronted plugin instead, I can configure the record storage page of the elements like this in typoscript setup of the frontend plugin:

```
plugin.tx_xyz_run {
    persistence {
        storagePid = 2,4,5,6,7,8,9
        recursiv = 1
        classes {
            XYZ\abc\Domain\Model\Rootobject {
                newRecordStoragePid = 2
            }
            XYZ\abc\Domain\Model\Inlineobject {
                newRecordStoragePid = 7
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I configure the backend of TYPO3 to put the inline elements of an aggregate root object into the same separate sysfolders in the backend when I create the object in the list-view, like I can do it with the frontend-plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible with `TCAdefaults`. See: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/17125#note-5

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I put this code into the Page TSConfig of the sysfolder/page where I create the root object. So the child element is located in the right subfolder with the id I choose, in this case 6:
`TCAdefaults.tx_myext_domain_model_modelname.pid = 6`

Comment: Looks like this TCAdefaults-settings are ignored when I use the Clipboard in TYPO3 (8.7.17) to copy/paste a rootobject in the sysfolder. All child-elements show up in the same sysfolder for the root object and **not** in the sysfolder defined by the TCA-settings. Any hints on that problem?

Comment: `TCAdefaults` is for creating new records. It's not for copy/pasting them. For a DB migration I recommend to do it directly in the DB table once.

Comment: Thank you for this information. But I dont do a DB migration. My task is to manage very complex records in the backend, in the role of an Editor. Records with many child-elements. I want to clone the object with all child-elements and then be able to modify the new elements. Thats why I liked to keep the structure.